# What is the meaning of "Fb::Error: A transaction has already been started"

Tags: ruby, firebird

I have a Ruby application that crashes sometimes with this error message:

> Fb::Error: A transaction has already been started)

I'm now wondering what this message means. I searched a little bit and I read that Firebird is not supporting nested transactions. Could the message hint to this? If not, what else could this mean?

Comment: "Fb::Error" is not Firebird message, it is most probably Ruby message. Firebird the server supports parallel transactions, which your language can reduce to nested ones, if it can not support independent parallel transactions. Assuming you have Firebird 2.5 or newer you can use TraceAPI (clients like fbProfiler.sf.net, IBExpert.net, built-in fbtracemgr and others) to see if the server has some transactions requests it returns errors for, if at all. But it sounds more like Ruby thing not Firebird thing.

Comment: You can search for the error text in your Ruby libraries and in your FB file like `c:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\firebird.msg` - did not find "A transaction has already been started" text there, so one more argument it is about Ruby not about Firebird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Firebird error message. It is an error message in the driver you're using. Specifically [here](https://github.com/rowland/fb/blob/master/fb.c#L928):

```c
static void fb_connection_transaction_start(struct FbConnection *fb_connection, VALUE opt)
{
    char *tpb = 0;
    long tpb_len;

    if (fb_connection->transact) {
        rb_raise(rb_eFbError, "A transaction has been already started");
    }

    if (!NIL_P(opt)) {
        tpb = trans_parseopts(opt, &tpb_len);
    } else {
        tpb_len = 0;
        tpb = NULL;
    }

    isc_start_transaction(fb_connection->isc_status, &fb_connection->transact, 1, &fb_connection->db, tpb_len, tpb);
    xfree(tpb);
    fb_error_check(fb_connection->isc_status);
}
```

Without in-depth familiarity with this driver, I'm guessing the problem is that you're trying to start a transaction on a connection that already has an active transaction.

Firebird itself supports multiple parallel transactions on a single connection, and it supports nested transactions in the form of SQL standard savepoints, but it looks like the driver you're using doesn't support this.

The solution (or workaround) would seem to be to either not start a transaction when you already have an active transaction, or to first commit or rollback an existing transaction before starting a new one.

Comment: ...or to have a pool of several connections, if what TS needs is parallel transactions and being nested is not requirement.